# Store JSON Object "as is" into datastore

Tags: go

I have to store a nested struct into datastore. As I'm running into the

datastore: flattening nested structs leads to a slice of slices: field

problem, I'd like to store the JSON object as is (as string?) to the datastore. Is this doable in Go?

Comment: what kind of "datastore" do you use? Can you share a code example, reproducing the error?

Answer (score 3):

Yes its doable in golang

However complex (or nested) your datastore is, it can be converted to json. Just make sure map's key is a string. 
Also make sure elements of the datastore are public (starting with capital letter). If you don't want to encode a field you can keep it as private (beginning with small letter).

json.Marshal() will return a byte array, which can be saved into a file.

```
type Complex struct {
  Data1 map[string]int
  Data2 []byte
  TimeStamp time.Time
}
type Datastore struct {
  Name string
  phones []string
  Address map[string]string
  noJson string // Wont be encoded as its not public
  SomethingComplex map[string]Complex
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to store the [json.RawMessage](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage). See [the example in the package docs](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#example_RawMessage).

> RawMessage is a raw encoded JSON object. It implements Marshaler and Unmarshaler and can be used to delay JSON decoding or precompute a JSON encoding.

It's a slice of `byte`, but you can easily convert it to a string if you wish.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it on a struct though. Assume, I've got a somewhat deeply nested struct (slices of slices, etc.) and want to store it into Datastore. How would I do this using RawMessage?